# AirPods sound is quieter on the right side

Tags: macbook-pro, iphone, airpods

My **right** AirPod connected to my Macbook Pro 2015 plays quieter than left. 
But if AirPods are connected to the iPhone everything works fine and both of them sounds good.

Any ideas or Solutions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check your System Preferences -> Sound -> Output (tab) -> Balance. Is it in the middle?

Comment: O my god! You are right! 
Silly me!

Comment: Will accept it as best answer in 10 mins. Rules of StackExchange

Comment: Hahaha, sometimes the most simple answers are the hardest to come up with. Have a nice day! :)

Comment: Wow, I thought mine was broken. Annoyed for whole week.

Comment: Glad to be of service  enjoy your Airpods, friendo!